# sed does not match equal sign or recognize special characters after the second slash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, whitespace

I am new to sed and am lost with this problem. There is one line in a text file:

```
 start_year                          = 1952,
```

I need to replace the start year number with the year number in an array, say time_c=(1999 01 01)

. So I tested the following command:

```
txt=" start_year                          = 1952,"
echo "$txt" | sed -r 's/([:blank:]*start_year[:blank:]*=) (.*)/\1 [:blank:]${time_c[0]}/g'
```

But this only gives back the original line stripped of white spaces:

```
start_year = 1952,
```

It seems that sed only recognizes the pattern if I remove the equal sign, because if I do

```
echo "$txt" | sed -r 's/([:blank:]*start_year[:blank:]*) (.*)/\1 = [:blank:]${time_c[0]}/g'
```

Then the result is:

```
start_year = [:blank:]${time_c[0]}
```

Now sed seems to have recognized correctly. But then, why is it not interpreting the [:blank:] and my variable?

Another minor thing is that I would like to keep the original whitespaces in the replaced text, if possible. It does not matter for my program, but it makes the replaced line align nicer with the others.

Could someone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shells don't do substitutions of any sort inside single quotes.

Also, the character classes are `[[:space:]]` with doubled brackets. You can do things like `[^[:space:][:digit:]]` too (not a space or digit). And the replacement text doesn't want `[:space:]` to appear — well, most probably it doesn't

This works:

```
time_c=(1999 01 01)
txt=" start_year                          = 1952,"
echo "$txt" | sed -r 's/([[:blank:]]*start_year[[:blank:]]*=) (.*)/\1 '"${time_c[0]}"'/g'
```

Note how the expansion of the shell variable is done outside of single quotes and inside of double quotes — that's generally a good idea (outside single quotes is crucial; inside double quotes is a good idea).

It produces:

```
 start_year                          = 1999
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the need for outer brackets now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$ time_c=(1999 01 01); echo " start_year                          = 1952," | 
sed -r "s/(\s*start_year\s+=\s*)(.*)(,)/\1${time_c[0]}\3/"

 start_year                          = 1999,
```